# Visual Studio Code stopped detecting errors

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working with Visual Studio Code v1.81.0.
I'm developing in Angular and C# - two different projects. Separate directories etc.
When I open my Angular project everything is fine.
When I open my C# project it stoped detecting errors.
I searched for a solution for a long time and came up with nothing.

When I go to the "problem" section (near the terminal) I see nothing.
Errors are not underlined (squiggle) in the source code.
I opened the settings (ctrl+shift+p) and I searched for "error squiggle" and "squiggle" and there is nothing.
I also searched for .vscode->settings.json and I don't have such a file.
I have the following extentions -

1. .NET Install Tool for Extension Aurhothors
2. Angular Language Service
3. c#
4. c# Extentions
5. Material Icon Theme
6. Prettier - Code formatter
7. Vetur

Everything was installed months ago.
I uninstalled and installed extensions 1, 3, 4, 6 but it did not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: possibly this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76850403/11107541