# How to remove vs code comments after every closing brackets

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

When I installed Microsoft C# extension (v2.0.357) (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp) there are auto comments after every "}" and also strange comments in my .py files after every ":". How to toggle this off

[image]

Comment: I found out that it only happens after you open a .cs file in vscode (it also happens when you do NOT have c# extension)

Comment: most likely they are NOT in the file but are a kind of decoration, find the extension that generates these decorations, use a different editor to verify if they are in the file or not

Comment: just to confirm- you don't see those when you disable that C# extension? Does it happen if yo rollback to v1 of that extension? Or if you [switch back to omnisharp instead roslyn in v2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76850403/11107541)?