# VS Code not highlighting syntax errors? (using C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I've been looking around the internet for this for days now and it's driving me crazy. I haven't changed any settings for my extensions, I have even disabled all of them except for the C# extension. I have 0 clue why this has happened.

[image]

This should very obviously be causing a syntax error

All the questions I've found about this have had basically the same answer of "Go to settings and enable error squigglies" Which I have looked for and apparently can't find? I'm sorry if I'm somehow being stupid and wasting your time this just happened one day and I need a way to fix it

Comment: what if you switch back to omnisharp rather than roslyn? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76850403/11107541

Comment: I guess we can chalk this up to bugs in the current roslyn-based intellisense of the C# extension.