# Using editor config with the C# plugin VSCODE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, editorconfig, omnisharp

I am trying to get linting to work on VS Code with an .editorconfig file in VS Code. I am not really at home in the C# ecosystem, so I tried following some guides. Like [this article](https://johnnyreilly.com/eslint-your-csharp-in-vs-code-with-roslyn-analyzers), most people suggest adding this to your settings.json:

```json
{
  "omnisharp.enableRoslynAnalyzers": true,
  "omnisharp.enableEditorConfigSupport": true
}
```

The first setting seems to be replaced by `"dotnet.backgroundAnalysis.analyzerDiagnosticsScope": "openFiles"` so I changed that, but I still do not get linting errors. The guide suggests restarting Omnisharp but there is no option for that anymore. It seems to me this is due to the .Net team [majorly changing the C# plugin](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5276), but I am confused as to what is actually happening and how I apply the "old" settings to the new system. It doesn't help that I don't know what to look for, and most articles aren't updated.

I guess my question is twofold:

1. Can someone explain what parts make up the C# tooling, and what is happening in the Ecosystem? Where should I look for linting options if not Omnisharp?
2. How can I apply the old Omnisharp settings, specifically the .editorconfig settings, to the new system?

Comment: not sure if related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76850403/11107541

Answer (score 0):

I should have just read on in the article . The errors don't actually become visible until you fail the build.